# I am trying to create a table in MySQL but I get the following error:

Tags: mysql

"Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'users_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'users'"

Here's what I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `books`;
CREATE TABLE `books`(
`title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`year` INT,
`edition` VARCHAR(10),
`authorLast` VARCHAR(10),
`authorFirst` VARCHAR(10),
`major` VARCHAR(4),
`courseNo` INT,
`profLast` VARCHAR(10),
`profFirst` VARCHAR(10),
`quality` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`user` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`ISBN` BIGINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`)
);

-- Users Table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users`(
`nameFirst` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`nameLast` VARCHAR(10),
`user` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`phoneNo` INT,
`major` VARCHAR(10),
`major2` VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `users` (`user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I've tried making the attributes unique because I read somewhere that that could be the problem but that doesn't seem to be my issue. I'm coming back to MySQL for the first time in a while so this can be a really simple error I'm just not seeing but I would appreciate the help! Thanks.

Comment: The foreign key in `users` is referencing itself.

Comment: Your problem is seemingly just a typo. You can actually have a foreign key that points to the same table, but not with the same column—the misleading error message probably reflects the internal problem that MySQL finds when trying to do so.

Comment: Please edit the title of this post to have the error message, or something that makes it obvious what this is about.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key in the users table is referring same user column in same table